# Codecs support disabled in Firefox

Tags: firefox, video, suse, youtube

In Firefox 61, under Tumbleweed I cant play videos from youtube, when checking for the html5, it says:

[image: firefox 61]
So I have been playing with the `about:config` and `about:buildconfig` but the mp4, h264, etc options are in true or enabled, and there is no support for gstreamer.

When the installation was just made there were some videos played, but now it doesnt play nothing.

**Update:** 
This is parcially solved updating to a new version via yast or downloading the program directly from mozilla site.